# discord.js Is the user phone verified?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Is the phone verified in the incoming message? How can I get the information?

my purpose; We have a private channel. Only verified phone users can send messages to this channel.

Is it possible with message event?

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if (/*Is the phone verified?*/) {
    console.log("verified!");
  }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, neither User nor GuildMember has this in Discord.js at the moment.  Either Discord.js hasn't added it, or it's not available in the Discord API.  ClientUser has a verified property, but that only applies to your bot's user, not the message sender, there is no way to retrieve that object type for a message sender that I can see.

Comment: @Tarazed thank you. I couldn't find it either. I wanted to ask. :(

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to know this information, since discord doesn't provide it using a bot client or OAuth2. However there's an option the the server settings to allow only users that has a verified phone number on their discord account to send messages.

To enable this go to Server Settings **>** Moderation **>** Select **"Highest"**

[Read more about "Verification Levels"](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/216679607-What-are-Verification-Levels-)

Comment: i know but i don't want to do it on server level. I only want one channel. I guess it's not possible. :(